# Update all with Loopback

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loopbackjs

I like Loopback but this is poorly documented/unexpected stuff here.

I want to use this functionality:

http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-updateall

I assume that

```
PUT /models
```

will invoke the `Model.updateAll()` functionality. The above HTTP request is standard out-of-the-box stuff, the stuff that Loopback is made for.

What I want to find out is the mapping between backend functions like Model.updateAll and the API URLs.

In other words, how can I find out if

```
PUT /Dogs ~ Dogs.updateAll()
```

isn't there a 1:1 mapping here? And if so, why is it not documented well?

Comment: this seems to have some useful info: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Working+with+data

Answer (score 2):

I don't think PUT supports the `where` filter. In your [link](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/PersistedModel+REST+API#PersistedModelRESTAPI-Updatemodelinstanceattributes) PUT requires a model ID instead of a filter.

So a valid request would be `PUT /dogs/1  {"color":"orange"}`

Answer (score 1):

Dear Loopback this is unexpected behavior on your part

this is how you expect us to do updateAll on a model/table

```
POST /dogs/update?where[color]=blue  '{"color":"orange"}'
```

but why can't we do it like this?

```
PUT /dogs?where[color]=blue   '{"color":"orange"}'
```

if this is the HTTP spec, then the HTTP spec is lame in this case.

I discovered the above info deep in the annals of Loopback lore here:

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/PersistedModel+REST+API#PersistedModelRESTAPI-Updatemodelinstanceattributes